# FromSql results in error, while query is working in pgAdmin

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In order to replace the following query which generate IN clause with 100+ elements inside and take 8.4 seconds:

```
List<AnalysisModel> analyses = AppDbContext.Analysis.Where(m => Id.Contains(m.TestId) & phasesAll.Contains(m.PhaseId)).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

I use manual query:

```
string analysisQuery = $"SELECT id, time, compound, reagent, product, phase, conc, test_id FROM public.analysis INNER JOIN (VALUES {stringHelper.WrapGuidToString(Id, GuidWrapper) } ) testid_val (v) ON (test_id = v) INNER JOIN (VALUES {stringHelper.WrapIntToString(phasesAll, IntWrapper) }) phase_val (p)ON (phase = p)";
List<AnalysisModel> analyses = AppDbContext.Analysis.FromSql(analysisQuery).AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

If I execute query generated in `analysisQuery` in pgAdmin it executes and provides the same table as the first expression (in 0.9 s). However when I execute through `FromSql` I receive the following error:

> System.FormatException: 'Index (zero based) must be greater than or
>   equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.'

Any suggestions why `FromSql` is not working correctly here?

`stringHelper.WrapGuidToString()` and `stringHelper.WrapIntToString()` wraps Guid and string into the appropriate format, e.g. ({Guid1}), ({Guid2}) and (1), (2) for Guid and Int respectively. The query generated via this method can be executed in pgAdmin without problems:

```
public string WrapIntToString(List<int> input, WrapModel wrapper)
{
 List<string> prep = new List<string>();
 input.ForEach(m => prep.Add(wrapper.LeftWrapper + m.ToString() + wrapper.RightWrapper));
 return string.Join(wrapper.Separator, prep);
}
```

`WrapGuidToString` code:

```
public string WrapGuidToString(List<Guid> input, WrapModel wrapper)
{
 List<string> prep = new List<string>();
 input.ForEach(m => prep.Add(wrapper.LeftWrapper + m.ToString() + wrapper.RightWrapper));
 return string.Join(wrapper.Separator, prep);
}
```

Where `wrapper` is

```
private WrapModel GuidWrapper => new WrapModel()
{
 LeftWrapper = "('{",
 RightWrapper = "}'::uuid)",
 Separator = ","
};
```

Comment: In which part of your code the error returns exactly.

Comment: In `List<AnalysisModel> analyses = AppDbContext.Analysis.FromSql(analysisQuery).AsNoTracking().ToList();`.

Comment: `FromSql` is your dll? if not then can you show some details here? `FromSql`

Comment: `FromSql` is a part of EF .Net Core, I do not know what is behind it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql

Comment: Did you try to run `FromSql` with a simple query? something like `select id, time, compound, from public.analysis` then pass this query to your `FromSql(analysisQuery)`

Comment: can you show your code `stringHelper.WrapIntToString`

Comment: Added code to the question body. This method has no issues, it generate a correct Sql query. `FromSql`  can easily perform simple queries, I think `join` is something which cause problems, however in pgAdmin both my query and entity framework inefficient query produces the same tables with the same headers, rows, columns.

Comment: can you show `WrapGuidToString` here?

Comment: It is the same as `WrapIntToString` just instead of `List<int>` it is `List<Guid>`. The wrapper creates the following line: ({Guid1}), ({Guid2}). And as I stated the Sql query is executable in pgAdmin, `FromSql` should be able to execute raw sql query too but it does not.

Comment: do have this code? `({Guid1}), ({Guid2}) and (1), (2)`

Comment: Added to the body of the question.

Comment: I Guess your error goes here `RightWrapper = "}'::uuid)",` try to investigate and check the content.

Comment: I changed this part to cast correct type. Otherwise error will occur in sql query itself.

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem:

```
wrapper.LeftWrapper + m.ToString() + wrapper.RightWrapper
```

It seems like you have created a string format `{yourStringValueHere}` that is why your got this error `Zero index`

```
String.Format("{0}{1}{2}","Value1","Value2","Value3")
```

It must look like that.

This one `m.ToString()` with your wrapper is wrong instead of an `integer` then followed by the value

Take a look at the content of your `WrapGuidToString` or `WrapIntToString` if it is in a correct format. This is your main issue here.

Comment: Nope, example of Sql query I am generating: `SELECT id, compound, conc, phase, product, reagent, test_id, time FROM public.analysis
INNER JOIN (VALUES ('{85025e34-b45c-412f-ba45-e2c49d2a3bae}'::uuid),('{11f99597-56a3-44bd-ad6c-9da16143057a}'::uuid) ) testid_val (v) ON (test_id = v) INNER JOIN (VALUES (2),(4),(5),(9)) phase_val (p) ON (phase = p)`. Again, it is working in pgAdmin. There is no wrong in my wrapping approach, it is not creating string values and when it looks like a string, I am casting a correct type via providing `::uuid`. Do not see your code working.

Comment: I think your `{}` VS consider this as string format. try it with a simple query like `select * from table` without any join.. if the error occur.

Comment: Simple queries like this it process easily. If I am not mistaken `FromSql` should just execute as is and receive table back and then if the table is incorrect format -- there error should happen. Since query is working I can only see that `FromSql` has problems. Without inner join there is no point for me because of performance.